# Flex: Binding to an MXML-esque "binding string" in action script?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, mxml

Is it possible to specify MXML-esque "binding strings" in ActionScript?

For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
MXMLBinding(this, "first_item",
            this, "{myArrayCollection.getItemAt(0)");
MXMLBinding(this, ["nameLbl", "text"],
            this, "Name: {somePerson.first} {somePerson.last}");
```

Edit: thanks for the responses and suggestions… Basically, it seems like you can't do this. I've dug around and figured out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I've done some digging, and here's what's up.

Bindings in MXML are, contrary to reason, setup by Java code (`modules/compiler/src/java/flex2/compiler/as3/binding/DataBindingFirstPassEvaluator.java`, if I'm not mistaken) at compile time.

For example, the binding: `first_item="{myArrayCollection.getItemAt(0)`}"` is expanded into, among other things, this:

```
    // writeWatcher id=0 shouldWriteSelf=true class=flex2.compiler.as3.binding.PropertyWatcher shouldWriteChildren=true
    watchers[0] = new mx.binding.PropertyWatcher("foo",
                                                 { propertyChange: true }, // writeWatcherListeners id=0 size=1
                                                 [ bindings[0] ],
                                                 propertyGetter);

    // writeWatcher id=1 shouldWriteSelf=true class=flex2.compiler.as3.binding.FunctionReturnWatcher shouldWriteChildren=true
    watchers[1] = new mx.binding.FunctionReturnWatcher("getItemAt",
                                                       target,
                                                       function():Array { return [ 0 ]; },
                                                       { collectionChange: true }, 
                                                       [bindings[0]],
                                                       null);

    // writeWatcherBottom id=0 shouldWriteSelf=true class=flex2.compiler.as3.binding.PropertyWatcher
    watchers[0].updateParent(target);

    // writeWatcherBottom id=1 shouldWriteSelf=true class=flex2.compiler.as3.binding.FunctionReturnWatcher
    // writeEvaluationWatcherPart 1 0 parentWatcher
    watchers[1].parentWatcher = watchers[0];
    watchers[0].addChild(watchers[1]);
```

This means that it is simply impossible to setup curly-brace MXML-style bindings at runtime because the code to do it does not exist in ActionScript.

Answer (score 2):

(Shameless plug)

[BindageTools](http://code.google.com/p/bindage-tools/) can do this:

```
Bind.fromProperty(this, "myArrayCollection", itemAt(0))
    .toProperty(this, "first_item");

Bind.fromAll(
    Bind.fromProperty(this, "somePerson.first"),
    Bind.fromProperty(this, "somePerson.last")
    )
    .format("Name: {0} {1}")
    .toProperty(this, "nameLbl.text");
```

Note that BindageTools puts the source object first and the destination last (whereas BindingUtils puts the destination first and the source last).

Answer (score 0):

I could use `BindingUtils` or `ChainWatcher`, but then I'd end up with code that looks something like this:

```
…
    BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateName, this, ["somePerson", "first"]);
    BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateName, this, ["somePerson", "last"]);
…
protected function updateName(...ignored):void {
    this.nameLbl.text = "Name: " + somePerson.first + " " + somePerson.last;
}
```

Which is just a little bit ugly… And the first example, binding to `arrayCollection.getItemAt(0)`, is even worse.

Comment: Curly brace {} binding is specific to MXML, and is not available in pure AS3. BindingUtils is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using ChangeWatcher (e.g., via BindingUtils.bindProperty or .bindSetter) is the way to go, yes.  I admit it's a strange notation, but once you get used to it, it makes sense, works perfectly and is quite flexible, too.

Of course, you could always wrap those functions yourself somehow, if the notation bugged you -- both methods are static, so doing so in a way that feels more appropriate to your application should be a fairly straightforward exercise.

Comment: It's not so much that the notation is strange… It's that it takes a whole lot more code, which is a whole lot more verbose, to accomplish exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think there's another way, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Does the first parameter (function) of `BindingUtils.bindSetter` method accept anonymous methods?

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(function()
  {
    this.nameLbl.text = "Name: " + somePerson.first + " " + somePerson.last;
  }, this, ["somePerson", "last"]);
```

I hate anonymous methods and obviously it's even more uglier - so I won't recommend that even if it works, but just wondering if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Never the answer anyone wants to hear, but just manage this stuff with getters/setters in ActionScript. With a proper MVC, it's dead simple to manually set your display fields.

```
public function set myArrayCollection(value:Array):void {
  myAC = new ArrayCollection(value);
  first_item = mcAC.getItemAt(0);  // or value[0];
}
```

etc....

Comment: The difficulty, though, is this won't bind to `myAC[0]`… To do that, I've got to add a `ChangeListener`, to myAC, and… (well, you know the rest of that story).

Comment: I guess my point is that programmers have been managing without binding for a long time. Usually a good architecture is sufficient. You might need a notification system where you can react to changes inside your AC.